# Force History.js to use hash URL fallback

Tags: javascript, html, history.js

Is it possible to force History.js - https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/ - to use the hash URLs in a browser which *does* support HTML5/history API?

This is only for local testing, so fiddling with the History.js source is fine if that's required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing for testing purposes and ended up updating the following lines in the jquery.history.js library.

**Original: ([View on GitHub](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/blob/master/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js))**

```
m.emulated={pushState:!Boolean(a.history&&a.history.pushState&&a.history.replaceState&&!/ Mobile\/([1-7][a-z]|(8([abcde]|f(1[0-8]))))/i.test(e.userAgent)&&!/AppleWebKit\/5([0-2]|3[0-2])/i.test(e.userAgent)),hashChange:Boolean(!("onhashchange"in a||"onhashchange"in d)||m.isInternetExplorer()&&m.getInternetExplorerMajorVersion()<8)}
```

**Hack Solution:**

```
m.emulated={pushState:true,hashChange:true}
```

I'm using the HTML4+HTML5 bundled minified code, but the line corresponds to Line 269 in the history.js uncompressed file. If you are using a different version, the corresponding section is here:

**Unminified Original ([View on GitHub](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/blob/master/scripts/uncompressed/history.js#L269)):**

```
History.emulated = {
pushState: !Boolean(
window.history && window.history.pushState && window.history.replaceState
&& !(
(/ Mobile\/([1-7][a-z]|(8([abcde]|f(1[0-8]))))/i).test(navigator.userAgent) /* disable for versions of iOS before version 4.3 (8F190) */
|| (/AppleWebKit\/5([0-2]|3[0-2])/i).test(navigator.userAgent) /* disable for the mercury iOS browser, or at least older versions of the webkit engine */
)
),
hashChange: Boolean(
!(('onhashchange' in window) || ('onhashchange' in document))
||
(History.isInternetExplorer() && History.getInternetExplorerMajorVersion() < 8)
)
};
```

**Hack Solution:**

```
History.emulated = {
    pushState: true,
    hashChange: true
    };
```

Comment: why the hell would they not make this default? Seems like everybody would want the `#` version to work?

Comment: @JamieHutber You do fall-back to hashes when the browser degrades - these code changes are to **force** the hash version on a HTML5 browser where you would normally use push state.

Comment: Headsup for new readers, history.js has an option for forcing the use of hashtag - From history.js documentation: History.options.html4Mode - If true, will force HTMl4 mode (hashtags)

Comment: Anyone got this in a plugin (or GreaseMonkey script) so it is disabled for all sites. I am sick of poorly implemented apps like Google Maps filling my history with hundreds of entries just because I moved the map around a bit, or sites with a scrolling feature that creates history entries as you scroll but never actually reloads what you had when you come back to them.