# Disable history api in firefox/chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, history.js

I would like to disable the history api in firefox, so history.js would use the fallback mechanism with a hash. This way it could be avoided to use IE for testing/development of the fallback functionality.

thanks

Comment: `window.history = null; delete window.history;` ?

Comment: seemingly is this property not removable. After your code is the property still there.

Comment: Actually, don't do the `delete window.history` part

Comment: This code still changes the url:
delete window.history;
window.history.pushState({}, "title", "/newpath");

Comment: I said **don't** include the `delete window.history;` part. **Only** execute `window.history = null;`...then try accessing `window.history` or `history`

Comment: I want this too, but in a plugin so it is disabled for all sites.  I am sick of poorly implemented apps like Google Maps filling my history with hundreds of entries just because I moved the map around a bit, or sites with a scrolling feature that creates history entries as you scroll but never actually reloads what you had when you come back to them.

Answer (score 0):

Ian, sorry. I've got you wrong. Yes, setting to null is working. The problem now is, that history.js makes it's own tests to determine history api availability. The only way to simulate the hash fallback i've found is patching the history lib: [Force History.js to use hash URL fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197048/force-history-js-to-use-hash-url-fallback)